# I want to calculate the difference between two columns as difference of months

Tags: r, date

I have a column ym1 as "202301" and ym2 as "202201" both in character data type.

I want to calculate the difference between both of these in the form of months.

Comment: `(zoo::as.yearmon(ym1, format = "%Y%m") - zoo::as.yearmon(ym2, format = "%Y%m")) * 12`

Answer (score 0):

You will require `tidyverse` which has the `lubridate` package among others.

Suppossing my data is the following, which I will call `df`

```
     ym1    ym2
1 202301 202201
```

Follow the steps below;

1. Format both the columns into `YYYY-MM` format by extracting substrings from the original column
2. Convert this string `YYYY-MM`into `Date` object
3. Use `interval` function from `lubridate` to find the interval between start and end date.
4. Divide (integer division using`%/%`) the `interval` output by 1 `month` to give number of months between the two columns

```
new_df <- df %>%
          mutate(ym1 = paste(substring(ym1, 1, 4), 
                             substring(ym1, 5, 6), 
                             sep = '-')) %>% 
          mutate(ym1 = as.Date(ym1, "%Y-%M")) %>% 
          mutate(ym2 = paste(substring(ym2, 1, 4), 
                             substring(ym2, 5, 6), 
                             sep = '-')) %>% 
          mutate(ym2 = as.Date(ym2, "%Y-%M")) %>% 
          mutate(month_diff = interval(ymd(ym2), ymd(ym1)) %/% months(1))
```

Output is given below;

```
             ym1        ym2 month_diff
    1 2023-03-10 2022-03-10         12
```